# Docker AWS ECS integration on Mac NoCredentialProviders error when running "docker compose up"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, dagster

When I am trying to run docker compose up to deploy my infrastructure to AWS using Docker's ECS integration. I'm getting the following error
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in the chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseError

I have created ecs context as below
docker context create ecs dagster-ecs -> (An existing AWS profile)

but while deploying
docker --context dagster-ecs compose --project-name dagster up

NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseError

Docker Compose File

```
---
version: "3.8"

services:
  # This service runs dagit. It has no user code; instead it loads its
  # jobs from the gRPC server running in the user_code service.
  # Because our instance uses the QueuedRunCoordinator, any runs submitted from
  # dagit will be put on a queue and later dequeued and launched by
  # the dagster-daemon service.
  dagit:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: dagit
    image: "$REGISTRY_URL/deploy_ecs/dagit"
    container_name: dagit
    command: "dagit -h 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -w workspace.yaml"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_DB: "postgres_db"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: "postgresql"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres_password"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_USER: "postgres_user"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - user_code
    x-aws-role:
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "ecs:DescribeTasks"
            - "ecs:StopTask"
          Resource:
            - "*"
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "iam:PassRole"
          Resource:
            - "*"
          Condition:
            StringLike:
              iam:PassedToService: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"

  # This service runs the dagster-daemon process, which is responsible for
  # taking runs off of the queue and launching them, as well as creating
  # runs from schedules or sensors.
  daemon:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: dagster
    image: "$REGISTRY_URL/deploy_ecs/daemon"
    container_name: daemon
    command: "dagster-daemon run"
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: "postgresql"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_USER: "postgres_user"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres_password"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_DB: "postgres_db"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - user_code
    x-aws-role:
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
            - "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition"
            - "ecs:DescribeTasks"
            - "ecs:ListAccountSettings"
            - "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition"
            - "ecs:RunTask"
            - "ecs:TagResource"
            - "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret"
            - "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
            - "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
          Resource:
            - "*"
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "iam:PassRole"
          Resource:
            - "*"
          Condition:
            StringLike:
              iam:PassedToService: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"

  # This service runs a gRPC server that serves information about your
  # repository. By setting DAGSTER_CURRENT_IMAGE to its own image, we tell the
  # run launcher to use this same image when launching runs in a new container.
  # Multiple containers like this can be deployed separately - each needs to
  # run on its own port and have its own entry in the workspace.yaml file.
  user_code:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: user_code
    image: "$REGISTRY_URL/deploy_ecs/user_code"
    container_name: user_code
    command: "dagster api grpc -h 0.0.0.0 -p 4000 -f repo.py"
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_DB: "postgres_db"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: "postgresql"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres_password"
      DAGSTER_POSTGRES_USER: "postgres_user"
      DAGSTER_CURRENT_IMAGE: "$REGISTRY_URL/deploy_ecs/user_code"

  # This service runs the postgres DB used by dagster for run storage, schedule
  # storage, and event log storage. In a real deployment, you might choose to
  # remove this in favor of an RDS instance.
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "postgres_db"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres_password"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres_user"
```

Comment: Have you set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables in the shell that you are running the command in? Also, you mentioned an existing AWS profile, so have you set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable?

Comment: @MarkB Yes, I have set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_PROFILE these variable in the shell